# Can I sync my forked branch without retaining the entire commit history?

Tags: git

I have a project that we customize but also take major releases from the upstream master branch. What I typically will do when a new release comes out is the following:

```
git checkout release
git fetch release
git checkout master
git merge release
```

My problem is that now every commit between point releases (those not done by my team, but by the open source community) show up in our `master` branch.

Can I update our forked projects without retaining the commit history from the upstream branch?

Comment: Would a squash commit work?

Comment: What is a forked branch? AFAIK a fork is a github term to mean a personal copy of another's repo. I'd normally just call it a clone...